# Can I use jq to prettify a file in place?

Tags: shell, jq

I've written a shell script to use jq to read a json file and write a pretty version of the file:

```
cat input.json | jq . > pretty.json
cp pretty.json ./input.json
rm pretty.json
```

Lines 2 and 3 were needed because

```
cat input.json | jq . > input.json
```

was leaving the file empty, is there a way to use shell/jq to prettyify the file in place without using a temporary file?

Comment: Not sure, but an alternative: `php -r 'file_put_contents($argv[1],json_encode(json_decode(file_get_contents($argv[1])), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));' input.json`

Comment: `echo "$(jq < input.json)" > input.json` also seems to work well enough.

Comment: @frabjous This forces the shell to store the processed document in memory and then invokes `echo` with the whole document as an argument.  If there are any escaped characters in the JSON document, like JSON encoded newlines and tabs, then these may be expanded by `echo`, breaking the structure of the document.

Comment: @Kusalananda If your `echo` implementation supports `-E`, like GNU's, it's probably a good idea to add that, in case you've changed the default, but apart from that, so long as you know you're using a version of echo that doesn't interpret such escapes, I don't see the problem. If you're using a lousy version of echo that doesn't let you control that, then, yes, that's a problem. Use a better one. Forcing the whole document in memory is clearly what the OP wants to do.

Comment: @frabjous Why use `echo` at all? `printf '%s\n' "$(...)"` would work just as well and have none of the issues that `echo` has. It still requires the shell to expand the whole document in a single string, though, which wouldn't be too elegant.

Comment: That works too. "Elegance" only matters for some use cases.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you can not process a file with `jq` and have it output the result to the original file.

You could use a temporary file like so:

```bash
cp   file.json      file.json.tmp &&
jq . file.json.tmp >file.json     &&
rm   file.json.tmp
```

This order of operations also ensures that the original file's metadata is retained. Since each step depends on the successful completion of the previous step (due to `&&`), you will not lose the document if e.g. `jq` fails to run for whatever reason.

You may use a tool such as GNU `sponge` (part of the `moreutils` package) to hide the manual labour of handling a temporary file:

```bash
jq . file.json | sponge file.json
```

Note that this is still using a temporary file behind the scenes.

As discussed in the comments to the question, you could use the fact that wrapping `jq` in a command substitution would force the shell to read the formatted JSON document before acting on a redirection on the same command line. Once read, the processed document may be written via a redirection using `printf`.

```bash
printf '%s\n' "$(jq . file.json)" >file.json
```

Note that this would not be a suitable solution if you are using a shell which does not have a built-in implementation of the `printf`  utility (or where this built-in utility has been disabled), as longer JSON documents would trigger an "Argument list too long" error.  Also note that the shell needs to store a complete copy of the document in memory, which means it would not be suitable to do this for very large documents.

Out of these three variants, it is only the first set of three commands that protects you from data loss in case your partition suddenly becomes full or `jq` fails to execute properly (due to being unavailable or because of an error in the input document).

Answer (score 1):

```bash
json-beautify-inplace () {
  temp=$(mktemp)
  printf 'input = %s\n' "$1"
  printf 'temp  = %s\n' "$temp"
  cp -- "$1" "$temp"
  jq . "$temp" > "$1"
}

json-uglify-inplace () {
  temp=$(mktemp)
  printf 'input = %s\n' "$1"
  printf 'temp  = %s\n' "$temp"
  cp -- "$1" "$temp"
  jq -r tostring "$temp" > "$1"
}
```

Comment: Using `jq -c .` instead of `jq -r tostring` would be better, and the "technical terms" for what you're doing are "pretty-print" and "compact".  See also GNU `sponge` (since you appear to be on a GNU system anyway).

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible to replace your `file.json` file is a copy of it, prettified with `jq`, without ever using a temporary file, but it is somewhat hackish:

```
( exec < file.json; rm file.json; jq . > file.json )
```

Some explanation about the “magic” in this command line:

- `exec < file.json` opens the original `file.json` file as standard input for the whole shell, so the upcoming commands will have this file as their standard input,
- `rm file.json` unlinks the file to ensure its content can’t be overwritten by the upcoming commands, but that content remains available as long as the file is kept open,
- `jq . > file.json` prettifies the JSON from the standard input to a new `file.json` file,
- the whole command line is wrapped in parentheses in order to run it in a subshell, so the deleted file is closed and the standard input is restored at the end.

Note you can write it in a slightly more compact way:

```
( rm file.json; jq . > file.json ) < file.json
```

Anyway, I would recommend using a temporary file rather than doing this!

Comment: This would probably be ok until you run it on a system where you forgot to install `jq`, or when you run it on the wrong file or a file with broken JSON. In short, there's not much scope for error recovery other than "restore from backup". It would be safer to move the file out of place instead of deleting it, but then there's suddenly no point in the `exec` and you might just as well do what I show in my answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda You’re 100%-right, I can’t find any good reason to do this, but I wanted to show that it is possible, just like it is possible to exchange the content of 2 integer variables without using a third variable.

Answer (score 0):

Since `jq` can't do this, I've defined this shell function in `.bashrc` and `.zshrc`:

```
prettify() {
    local temp_file
    temp_file=$(mktemp) &&
      jq . < "$1" > "$temp_file" &&
      mv -- "$temp_file" "$1"
}
```

`prettify foo.json` now does what I needed.

Comment: Beware it will likely affect the permissions and ownership of file (`mktemp` creates files readable to the owner only) and breaks hard links and symlinks. As mktemp creates files in /tmp by default and `/tmp` is often on a separate filesystem, that would become a remove+copy instead of just rename